# Distribution upgrade hanged

Tags: 16.04

I have running Ubuntu distro 16.04 LTS and tried to upgrade to 18.04 LTS, it got strucked at the following

[image]

I have not tried any solution which may damage the upgrades.

How to resolve it  ?? Do i need to download or reinstall everything ?

(I have already installed Windows 8 on my system)  Please help

Comment: How long has it been strucked?

Comment: I kept waiting for 3 hours and it resumed slowly and finally finished. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did an upgrade to 18.4,rather just a clean install. So i'm not sure if this will help. Try sudo apt-get install -f to fix broken packages.

TC.